# How do I optimize MySQL Server for better performance?

Tags: performance, mysql, sql-server, optimize

Recently I had to work with a legacy system. Working with it took a lot of my time because many of the tables were not normalized properly. Due to maintenance issues it is impossible to change. My senior engineer told me to optimize the MySQL server for better performance and speed.

I changed my `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini` file to be the following:

```
key_buffer_size = 128M 30% of your memory (Max 4GB)
max_allowed_packet = 5M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 10M
read_buffer_size = 20M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 30M
thread_concurrency = 8
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 256
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G  to 50% - 70% of your ram.
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1G to to 10% of ram
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G (Max 4GB) larger the file recovery slow.
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

It works fine at first. However after a few hours I couldn't start MySQL and I had to reinstall MySQL Server.

What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What did the logs say? Oh and is that the actual content? `1G (Max 4GB) larger the file recovery slow.` looks like something copy pasted without even bothering to think about what it says.

Comment: yes it was a copy paste. my friend's process got speed than before after changing those values i my.ini

Comment: Still without any further information on the specs of the machine, what engine the DB uses and what the actual error was that prevented MySQL from coming up you won't get any useful information (probably) and as you just said it's not even the live configuration. Why did you change the configuration in this way? Especially "reinstall the server" shouldn't be necessary if it was a configuration error. In addition it looks like you made [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231896/how-to-optimize-mysql-server-for-better-performance) post over at Stackoverflow as well?

Comment: yes this is a copy of it. I wanted to get a quick answer for this. Since it last post didn't get any answer I decided to post it here. It shows db engine is InnoDB. And there was no errors. @seth

Comment: So how did you determine that you couldn't start MySQL if there were no errors? Why did you decide to reinstall it? Please provide answers to the other questions as well. What's the usage pattern of the DB?

Comment: Only error was while I double clicking the localhost there was a error prompt saying "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)" in navicat.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get some perspective of the extract of your config file I did a comparison to the default value ([1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html),[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html)). The notation is going to have the parameter followed by your value and the default one in parenthesis.

```
key_buffer_size = 128M (8M)
max_allowed_packet = 5M (4M)
table_open_cache = 256 (2000)
sort_buffer_size = 10M (2M)
read_buffer_size = 20M (1M)
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M (2M)
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M (8M)
thread_cache_size = 8 (-1)
query_cache_size= 30M (0/1M)
thread_concurrency = 8 (10)
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 256 (8M)
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G (128M)
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1G (8M)
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1G (8M)
innodb_log_file_size = 1G (5M)
innodb_file_per_table = 1 (Off/On)
```

As we can see you increased most caches considerably. But does that make sense? You said your DB is using the InnoDB engine. According to the above documentation `key_buffer_size`, `read_buffer_size`, `bulk_insert_buffer_size` only applies to MyISAM databases. I'm not sure whenever temporary spaces would be running on that.

Using `myisam_sort_buffer_size` seems backwards especially since the documentation states: `The size of the buffer that is allocated when sorting MyISAM indexes during a REPAIR TABLE or when creating indexes with CREATE INDEX or ALTER TABLE.` So it would be used rarely in most normal use cases.

In addition you're using the following settings which seems to heavily rely on your DB usage pattern `max_allowed_packet`, `table_open_cache`, `thread_cache_size`, `innodb_log_buffer_size` but you didn't say anything about the usage patterns. So consider looking into the above documentation to have a look at what they actually do and compare them to the usage pattern of the DB.

Beware that `sort_buffer_size` and `read_rnd_buffer_size` is reserved per session. Some of the MyISAM parameters might be as well so you really do get quite a bit of overhead for each session. Again you need to evaluate the actual usage pattern.

Now for the InnoDB settings which you specified. `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` is deprecated. It's not clear why you'd modify `innodb_log_file_size`, `innodb_file_per_table` not sure what your reason for that change might be. The latter might just be default of `On`? By setting the remaining setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to such a high value you might want to consider using `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` as well.

Overall it looks like you just tried something and it didn't work. According to your comments you didn't even look at the MySQL log files to figure out what was responsible for the service not accepting connections or not coming up at all. If you really want to optimize the DB performance you will have to do that. Consider using additional indexes on tables where it's sensible in order to increase the query performance and have a look at what queries are actually being executed on the DB. In addition try to get an understanding of what usage pattern the DB has in terms of the number of connections and size of queries.

Comment: Good advice, here.  `table_open_cache` is an especially delicate value that should probably be removed from the config entitely, unless there is a very specific reason and accompanying testing to justify the change.  Mentioned [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45570/11651) along with my all-time favorite quote: *"'Tuning' your server can be a stunning waste of time."*